# Why TypeScript compiler ignores 'noImplicitThis' option in my example?

Tags: function, typescript, this, implicit, anonymous

Consider the code:

```
class x {
    public variable: number = 0;
    public x() {
        const c = [];
        c.push({
            xxx () {
                console.log(this.variable);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The anonymous function xxx doesn't have access to 'this' of class 'x'. Normally this can only compile if 'this' implicitly has type any. [But it does compile](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20x%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20variable%3A%20number%20%3D%200%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20x()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20c%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20c.push(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20xxx%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(this.variable)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A).

If I extract my literal object in a separate value, I actually [do get a compilation error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20x%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20variable%3A%20number%20%3D%200%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20x()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20c%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20tt%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20xxx()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(this.variable)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20c.push(tt)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A) that I expect.

Is it a compiler bug?

Note: you need to manually enable 'noImplicitThis' in typescript playground because apparently options are not sharable.

Comment: Interesting .. might be a bug..

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir, fyi: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25526